# Run a Batch File OnClick of Button from DOM in Node-Webkit App

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

I cannot seam to figure this out please help me run "run.cmd" onclick of button from my nwjs application.

```
<button onclick="runHelperProcess()">Run Process</button>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runHelperProcess() {
        gui.Shell.openItem('run.cmd');
    }
</script>
```

run.cmd is located in the root dir of the nw application.

Comment: sorry if this does not follow the guidelines properly i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: If you're new to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve] ... you should for example say what happens / what exception you get (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button onclick="require('child_process').spawn('YourBat.bat'),[]);">Run Process</button>
```

NB: It assumes the batch file is in the same directory as your app.

Comment: still does not seem to want to work. This is proving hard haha Since its crominium based perhaps maybe i have to give the browser permission to access on system level somehow?